# How to make folded sails with rope animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I recently saw a video of a guy who had done a simulation of sails folding, from what he said in response to a comment, an object was used to get stuck on one end of the rope and then he was animated to pull it and consequently doubling the sail, I tried to reproduce the effect by watching some simulation tutorials, but I was not successful, there were many problems with the collision and the system did not respond correctly.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/jzKBwFAuX-I

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy task ... cloth collision is always tricky ... here something with self-collision enabled (to prevent intersection seen in video).

[image]

With one more subdivision more details, but also more collision artefacts ...

[image]

Usually when objects start to penetrate into each other you should increase distance collision.

Since my "rope" is single sided I switched Normal orientation inside.
Suggestion - Simulate "rope" as simple mesh (like a proxy) and hires model use just for final rendering.

[image]

Comment: You saved me with these tips, but I'm still curious how the guy in the video managed to use an animation of a string being pulled down to reproduce this effect. I think of a scenario where I would do an animation and I would need something like this